# how to set the data-value to div under div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added this but gives error

[image: error]

I want to get and set the numerical value but it gives undefined
    `$('#List').find('.plan').dataset.value = 10;`

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an DOM property on a jQuery COLLECTION.

To access the element when [using dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) you need [0] as in

```
$('#List').find('.plan')[0].dataset.value = amt;
```

if you do not want to use `.data("value",amt)` or `.attr("data-value",amt)` which will set the amt on ANY .plan found.

Alternative you can use `this`:

```
$('#List').find('.plan').each(function() {
  this.dataset.value = amt; 
})
```

Testing:

```js
var amt = 10;

// $('#List').find('.plan').dataset.value = amt; // does not work

$('#List').find('.plan')[1].dataset.value = amt; // ONLY on second element
console.log($("#List").html())

$('#List').find('.plan').attr("data-value", amt); // on ALL elements found
console.log($("#List").html())

$('#List').find('.plan').each(function() { // loop over elements
   this.dataset.value = 20; 
})
console.log($("#List").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="List">
  <li class="notPlan">Not a plan</li>
  <li class="plan">Plan 0</li>
  <li class="notPlan">Not a plan</li>
  <li class="plan">Plan 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i guess there's no need to use [0] because element is being selected through id which is always unique . Am i correct ?

Comment: @PrinceArora So I tested this. The error is that the find returns a collection and you need to access the single element when using dataset as opposed to attr - see update

Comment: yes  i tried too it returns array of element and if used without [0] it is implemented to every element with class .plan in #list

Answer (score 2):

Use `.attr`, to set the value of `data-value` attribute, which will set the value on all `.plan`

```
$('#List').find('.plan').attr("data-value", "10");
```

Comment: how can i set the value form another variable?

Comment: @KaranKapadni oh you just need to replace `"10"` with the variable name. I would suggest you to go through the basics of JS.

Comment: The code above will set amt on ALL .plan in the list - that is not necessarily what is  OP wanted

Comment: `Thank you! :) i got it solved` I guess he got it solved :)

Comment: I guess he THINKS he got it solved until he adds a plan ;)

Comment: @mplungjan yea but let him figure out some stuff :)

Comment: At least he has the full story now :)